# Is the capacity of absorbtion of gamma rays by a material dependent on its temperature?

Tags: temperature, absorption, gamma-rays

Is the capacity of absorbtion of gamma rays by a material dependent on its temperature? As electrons heat up a wire that wire increases its resistance to the current. Is it same regarding gamma ray flow?

Comment: Similar to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/657648/is-liquid-lead-better-gamma-ray-absorber-than-solid-lead?noredirect=1#comment1474736_657648 and my comment there applies equally well here.