# Is liquid lead better gamma ray absorber than solid lead?

Tags: absorption, gamma-rays, elements

Is liquid lead better gamma ray absorber than solid lead? Can this be compared with the fact that an el.conductor has more resistance to current at higher temperatures? If yes could it be used in astronautics?

Comment: Apart from density differences, there are still the same number of electrons in (from a gamma ray point of view) the same energy levels. Particularly all the deeper valence electrons don't care if they are in a liquid or a solid, and the outer ones have an energy very small compared with the gamma. So, no, there would be no difference.

Comment: @JonCuster your comment appears to address $\frac{dE}{dx}$, which isn't the mechanism for shielding $\gamma$'s.

Comment: @JEB - Well, yes, gamma-electron interactions are definitely a component of shielding (absorbing) gammas. For radiation effects in semiconductors one worries a lot about energy going into the electronic system. Your other option is interactions with the nuclei, and those energy levels really really really don't care about the phase (liquid vs solid) of the material.